# doubtful replace of Macro with Static Const varaible

Tags: c++, macros, static, constants

I want to replace

```
#define SomeValue ':'
```

with

```
static const uint8_t SomeValue = ':';
```

I am doubtful of this replace-with, is it correct to replace this macro with static const?

Comment: Why not a `char`? And I don't think you need the `static`.

Comment: By looking at it, It is correct

Comment: Yes. Macros are evil, but not always. But in your case don't use a macro.

Comment: Depends on the surroundings. I sometimes got errors of multiple definitions when changing from Macro to a static const, but that depends on how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

From *Scott Meyers* Effective C++

**Item 1:  Prefer const and inline to #define.**

This Item might better be called "prefer the compiler to the preprocessor," because `#define` is often treated as if it's not part of the language per se. That's one of its problems. When you do something like this,

```
#define ASPECT_RATIO 1.653
```

the symbolic name `ASPECT_RATIO` may never be seen by compilers; it may be removed by the preprocessor before the source code ever gets to a compiler. As a result, the name `ASPECT_RATIO` may not get entered into the symbol table. This can be confusing if you get an error during compilation involving the use of the constant, because the error message may refer to 1.653, not `ASPECT_RATIO`. If `ASPECT_RATIO` was defined in a header file you didn't write, you'd then have no idea where that `1.653` came from, and you'd probably waste time tracking it down. This problem can also crop up in a symbolic debugger, because, again, the name you're programming with may not be in the symbol table.

The solution to this sorry scenario is simple and succinct. Instead of using a preprocessor macro, define a constant:

```
const double ASPECT_RATIO = 1.653;
```

In the same vein

From *Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu* C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices

**16. Avoid macros**

Macros remain the only solution for a few important tasks, such as `#include` guards `#ifdef` and `#if` defined for conditional compilation, and implementing assert.

For conditional compilation (e.g., system-dependent parts), avoid littering your code with `#ifdef`s. Instead, prefer to organize code such that the use of macros drives alternative implementations of one common interface, and then use the interface throughout.

You may want to use macros (cautiously) when the alternative is extreme copying and pasting snippets of code around.

Comment: And also type safety, you're always sure of what you're using (as far as concerns type checking)